# Hibernate validator 7.0.4

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee

One of the requirements to our project is to migrate to latest Hibernate validator. I did modify the pom.xml and updated the version (6.1.x) to (7.0.x). The projects report issues like compile error and/or @Unit test code failures.

Researching further, noticed that with hibernate validator 7.0.x, they no longer support javax.validation but replaced with jakarta.validation. They have a pre-req version which I have updated it on the pom.xml. I am still facing some issues with compile or build error.

Questions:

1. Is it sufficient to only use jakarta.validation for javax.validation?
2. Do we have to modify all of javax packages? Lile javax.servlets, javax.persistence etc.

If all of javax has to be replaced with jakarta. Do we have jakarta servlets that support the web service?

Any help here is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hibernate Validator 7 isn't compatible with the current released versions of Spring due to the move to Jakarta. That is only supported for the upcoming Spring 6 and Spring Boot 3. So you cannot upgrade to 7, use the latest 6.x version instead. If you don't validation in Spring won't work anymore.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I noticed the same too. Trying to understand few other things here. Hibernate Validator 7 -> will it require all of Javax packages to be Jakarta? Or only the Javax.validations? 

Reason is, I am trying to get the application load without the validation. And seeing instances of other Javax packages to be not supported. So trying to understand the complexity of this change.

Comment: Only the javax.validation ones as that is what you change, but it will disable validation (and might lead to issues with classcast etc. ).

Comment: Ok. Thank you so much. I read it in a thread somewhere saying JavaEE is no longer supported with Hibernate Validator 7. So all of javaee-api like Javax.Servlet, Javax.Persistance are all impacted too.

Comment: If its only the Javax.validation packages that are impacted, why wouldn't Jakarta.validation dependency not work. Sorry. I don't have enough expertise on why this is an issue with Spring and trying to understand more to it.

Comment: Because Spring doesn't support JakartaEE yet... It only knows the `javax.validation` api and **not** the `jakarta.validation` API. Hence it won't work. Because you are only upgrading that part. If you would move to Tomcat 10, you would also have the Jakarta version of the Servlet-API. So only validation is impacted because that is **what you are uprgading**. Moving from JavaEE to JakartaEE impacts **all** API's that use JavaEE, which is why a framework cannot (or won't) use both as it will be nearly impossible to use both at the same time (or even worse have a mix).

Comment: One quick question on the same lines here. My project is not spring. It is a generic web application. I replaced all of Javax.validation to Jakarta.validation and modified the pom.xml to use Hibernate Validator to use 7.0.4 and Org.glassfish artifact of Jakarta.el (4.0.1). Is this an acceptable migration to latest Hibernate validator?

Comment: WARNING: Unknown HK2 failure detected:
MultiException stack 1 of 3
javax.validation.NoProviderFoundException: Unable to create a Configuration, because no Bean Validation provider could be found. Add a provider like Hibernate Validator (RI) to your classpath

Comment: I am still seeing the error reported as if the Javax.validation is being used and not Jakarta validation.

Comment: NO it isn't an acceptable migration as Hibernate Validator is JakartaEE **not** JavaEE as I said in my initial comment already.